# Fullcalendar eventDrop with Timeline View

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the new Timeline view in the FullCalendar from http://fullcalendar.io/
When I drag an event, I want to save the change to the backend, so I use the eventdrop function like this:

```
 eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, ev) {
            console.log(event.title + " was dropped on Date:" + event.start.toISOString() + " ResourceID:" + event.resourceId);             
        }
```

The problem is, that I have events shared among multiple resources, so I need to know the source of the event begin dropped (the resourceId where it came from) to be able to update correctly. In my backend I handle the link between a resource and the event via a field called event.resourceIds holding the ids of all the resources linked to this event. In the front end (Fullcalender), I create an event (with a unique ID) for each each resource for a given event.

Any hints on how I can find out where the event came from?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution myself - posted here in case anyone could use the answer:

```
   eventDragStop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, ev) {
        event._srcResourceId = event.resourceId;
    },
    eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, ev) {
        console.log(event.title + " was dropped on Date:" + event.start.toISOString() + " ResourceID:" + event.resourceId + ' Old resource ID: '+ event._srcResourceId);           
    }
```